# F-split $SO(2)$ is isomorphic to $GL(1)$?

Tags: algebraic-groups, automorphic-forms

Let $F$ be a number field and $\chi$ is a character of $\mathbb{A}^{\times}/F^{\times}$.

In some paper, it is written that we can consider $\chi$ as a representation of $F$-split $SO(2)$.

I am wondering whether $F$-split $SO(2)$ isomorphic to $GL(1)$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried to describe $SO_2(K)$ for any field $K$ of characteristic $\neq 2$ in my answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3049844/96384. It is $K$-split if and only if $K$ contains a square root of $-1$. If it does, the group is isomorphic to $GL_1(K) \simeq K^\times$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, Oh I just saw your answer. Your previous answer in stackexchange really helpful to me. Thank you very much!